# execute script tag with jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am replacing the content of my page by using jQuery.load but the page which I am loading using jQuery.load contains an advertisement in div tag like this - `<div><script language="JavaScript" src="zedo url"></script></div>`. 
When I replace the code it gives me only  tag without the advertisement.

Here is my code --

```
$("#main-wrapper").load(ajax_url + " #main-wrapper"  , function() {

                    });
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: How do you load your ad in your tag ?

Comment: "If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed." per [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution)

Comment: I have a script tag -- when i add this script tag in html it gives me the advertisement --

Comment: @PaulRoub So what can I do in this case ?